# 100% Height & Width of container div tag not working

Tags: css, html, height, width

I have a following layout of my web page. Following CSS code gives me 100% Height & Width in Internet Explorer 9. While same does gives me 100% width in FF & Chrome but not 100% height. I tried several example most of them have the same issue. I have use same code on http://jsfiddle.net/cwkzq/3/ here if i view same it FF it gives me 100% height as well as width.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
            }
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                border: 1;
                background-color:Aqua;
            }
            .Container {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                border: solid 1px red;
                margin: 0 auto;
                padding: 0 1em;
                font: 12px/1.5 Verdana;
                background-color:red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <!--  Container    -->
    <div class="Container">
        <!--  TopMenu Bar    -->
        <div class="colorBar">
        asd
        </div>
        <!--  TopMenu Bar   -->
        <!--  Middle Part    -->
        <div class="MiddleWrapper">
            <!--  Left Title    -->
                <div class="Title">

                </div>
            <!--   Left Title   -->
            <!--   Large Image   -->
                <div class="ImageLeftWrapper">

                </div>
            <!--   Large Image   -->
            <!--  Logo Wrapper    -->
                <div class="LogoWrapper">

                </div>
            <!--   Logo Wrapper   -->
            <!--   Page Text Area  -->
                <div class="PageText">

                </div>
            <!--   Page Text Area   -->
            <!--  Search Bar    -->
                <div class="SearchBar">

                </div>
            <!--   Search Bar    -->
            <!--   Banner Images -->
                <div class="BannerImageWrapper">

                </div>
            <!--  Banner Images   -->
        </div>
        <!--  Middle Part    -->
        <!--   Menu Wrapper    -->
        <div class="MenuWrapper">

        </div>
        <!--   Menu Wrapper    -->
        <!--   Footer Section  -->
        <div class="FooterWrapper">

        </div>
        <!--  Footer Section  -->
    </div>
    <!--  Container   -->
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I would appreciate if someone can point to the problem in the code.

Comment: I'd suggest you include a DOCTYPE tag, this way you'll always know that is not the source of the problem ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Setting the height to a percentage only has effect when the parent element also has a height set. So if you want to set the div to 100% height, you also have to set the form and the body to 100% height.

Comment: Yes, You are absolutely right i forgot to mention the form height ` html, body, form{ height: 100%;}` It is working now. These minor mistake can be so expansive at times. Thanks

Comment: A perfect example though not relevant here is always contain your floats. If it's not inside a block level wrapper it will float off into oblivion. The same is true when using % to set values. They are contingent upon their parent containers by default. i.e. if p {font-size: 90%} and p p {font-size: 90%} <p><p>foobar</p></p> would get you 90% of 90% which is 81%. So foobar would be output in 81% font-size. It took me a while to realize just HOW CASCADING style sheets CASCADE. I knew they did but not to this level until recently.