# Having problems with HTML body width and height

Tags: html, css

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913251/100-height-width-of-container-div-tag-not-working), I declared my HTML and body to 100% height and width. However it leaves a space in the bottom which I cannot remove.

What is the problem? If I just erase that statement and leave everything like that all things with percentage height and width vanishes.

I have also set margin and padding as zero, it is leaving a space of about 5% height of HTML. I have seen everything in inspect elements in Chrome and it show that the extra space is contained in the body and nowhere else.

Comment: Please post your code which causes problem.

Comment: it is a very big code how can i post it

Comment: body has a margin of 8px. add this to your body css `margin:0; padding:0;`

Comment: Are you using the exact same `HTML` and `CSS` as that example. Because it sounds like you might not be resetting the default browser styles.

Comment: "it is a very big code how can i post it " — You take stuff away until you have the smallest amount of code that can reproduce it. See http://sscce.org/

Comment: @AnkitLadhania — Several people have helped. Several people have told you what you need to do before we can give you any more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have copied the exact same code of that question in your HTML document, you need to remove `padding` and `border` properties as that adds width to your element

```
.Container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: solid 1px red; /* Remove this */
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 1em; /* Remove this */
    font: 12px/1.5 Verdana;
    background-color:red;
}
```

[The one which have scroll bars](http://jsfiddle.net/RdzPG/)

[Fixed one](http://jsfiddle.net/RdzPG/2/)

Explanation: If you see the box model below

[image]

Padding and Border is counted outside the element, so as your container element is 100% width already it adds `1em` on both the sides of the element

Comment: i have seen every thing in inspect elements in chrome and it show that the extra space is contained in the body nowhere else

Comment: @AnkitLadhania are you sure you've done what quentin told you to do? Also did you applied my solution?

Comment: i just took the body and height part from the given fiddle noting else i'm doing something else

Comment: @AnkitLadhania If the child elements have margins or paddings, this will result in page scroll

Comment: it is scrolling but chrome is showing not part of child elements that have that large padding and margin

Comment: @AnkitLadhania We cannot do anything unless and until you post your CSS here

Answer (score 2):

All else being equal, browsers will add default margin and/or padding to the html and/or body elements.

100% plus some margin or padding is more than 100% and will create scrolling.

Remove it to remove the scrolling.

```
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: It will scroll if he has explicit margins/paddings on parent elements

Comment: @alien please explain what u mean

Answer (score -1):

```
simply give 
body
{
margin:0px;
}
```

Comment: I think the OP has already done that.